# java.lang.IllegalStateExeption: Could not find a method finishA(View) in the activity class

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am new to Android. I have started doing with ActivityLifeCycle app. In this I have 3 activity classes. From first activity I want to go to second activity class using intents when a button is clicked in the 1st activity. But it is giving error. And I have imported correct `android.view.View` package.

The same question was asked by someone else earlier, but I didn't get the solution,
here is the error-prone code.

activity_main.xml:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:onClick="startActivityB"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="startb" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
    android:onClick="finishA"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="FinishA" />

<Button
```

MainActivity.java: (and this is the 1st activity)

protected void startActivityB(View v) {

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity_B.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
protected void finishA(View v)
{
    MainActivity.this.finish();
}
```

**This are the errors I got in logcat:**

```
D/Avtivity_A(1333): onStart()of Activity_A started
D/Avtivity_A(1333): onResume()Activity_A started
D/AndroidRuntime(1333): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(1333): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
E/AndroidRuntime(1333): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(1333): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method
     finishA(View) in the activity class com.example.lifecycle.MainActivity for
     onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button2'
E/AndroidRuntime(1333):   at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2059)
E/AndroidRuntime(1333):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
E/AndroidRuntime(1333):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
E/AndroidRuntime(1333):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(1333):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(1333):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(1333):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(1333):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(1333):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(1333):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(1333):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(1333):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: finishA(View) what is this function are you sure it is there in your code or is it finish(); and you misplaced something

Comment: You rare shwoing the XML for button1 but the error seems to be in button2, so please show the correct files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your xml for the activity you defined an onClick handler, and this name is the function name of the handler. I think you didn't implement the function.

i.E.

in the XML you have :

```
android:onClick="finishA"
```

and in the class you must implement a function:

```
public void finishA(View view)
{
}
```

Not sure if this is the cause, but it looks like it. If not, then post the XML and the class (the relevant parts of it).

**Update**

In your question the error references button2 and your XML is about button1, so you should show us the correct files.

**Update**

Your onClick handler is `protected` but it needs to be `public` as in the sample I showed above. When I test this in my app I get the same error when I make it protected.

Comment: i think OP has changed the question after your answer was posted there is no line for `android:onClick="finishA"`

Comment: Yeah, the XML was not there, so I assumed that this is the cause because the question was incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you have called a function somewhere (Not in the code you have provided in your question)

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method
>        finishA(View) in the activity class com.example.lifecycle.MainActivity for
>        onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button2'

It says that in your mainActivity the function which is implemented on `button2` click not the `button1` which you shown in your code.
it may Contains a line which says a call to `finishA(View v)` and when the compiler search for the same it is missing in the declaration of the class.

**After Update to question**

as suggested by Devolus You have used protected access modifier for your function `finishA()` you should use public for the same one instead of protected.

If you use protected as an access modifier then it makes the function available only to the class and the subclasses of the same class. Because of which when you are calling the `finishA()` from your activity B it is not able to find out the `finishA()` function.

The Protected variables and methods allow the class itself to access them, classes inside of the same package to access them, and subclasses of that class to access them

Where as using public access modifier the function will be available to each class which implements an object of the class `Activity-A`

You can read more at : http://www.java-made-easy.com/java-access-modifiers.html

and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private) question on SO will be helpful

You can also go on to use protected access modifier in your function if your bothe `Activity-A`and `Activity-B` classes are in same package , by creating an object of class `Activity-A` in `Activity-B` class (note: if you are going to use class name without creating an object you will have to use `protected static` while declaring the function.)

With

```
protected void finishA(View v)
{
    MainActivity.this.finish();
}
```

Call the method in Activity-B class as(it will work only If the both classes are in same package)

```
ActivityA obj = new ActivityA ();
obj.finishA(View v);
```

With

```
 public void finishA(View v)
    {
        MainActivity.this.finish();
    }
```

Call the method in Activity-B class as

```
ActivityA obj = new ActivityA ();
obj.finishA(View v);
```

With

```
 public static void finishA(View v)
    {
        MainActivity.this.finish();
    }
```

Call the method in Activity-B class as

```
ActivityA.finishA(View v);
```

with

```
 protected static void finishA(View v)
    {
        MainActivity.this.finish();
    }
```

Call the method in Activity-B class as(it will work only If the both classes are in same package)

```
ActivityA.finishA(View v);
```